# Sql 2008 query problem - which LatLong's exists in a geography polygon?

Tags: sql-server-2008, latitude-longitude, geography

i have the following two tables:-

GeoShapes

- GeoShapeId INT IDENTITY
- Name VARCHAR(100)
- ShapeFile GEOGRAPHY  [ this is a closed Polygon of Lat/Longs ]

CrimeLocations

- CrimeLocationId INT IDENTITY
- LatLong GEOGRAPHY   [ this is a Lat/Long Point ]

Now, i have around 10K GeoShape results and around 500CrimeLocations.

*I'm trying to figure out which GeoShapes all 500 crime lat/long points exist inside of.*

:( I just don't get it! I was trying to do an `STIntersects` on a subquery but that didn't work. Any suggestions?

cheers!

EDIT 1: I cannot use any `GEOMETRY` functions .. because (as stated above) these are all geography types.

EDIT 2: I know how to use `STContains` and `STIntersects`. Please don't provide basic examples of that. I'm more curious about to do a complex query with my table structure, above.

Comment: You should paste what you have tried and why didn't it work. That would probably give you better advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding your 'edits', it's not often you see a question that includes "please don't provide...". Surely every little bit helps? Particularly since you haven't actually shown us what you *do* know about `STContains` or `STIntersects` (or `Filter()` for that matter)...

Anyway, I had a database of zipcodes and storelocations handy, so I renamed the tables/columns to match yours (I then have 6,535 CrimeLocatoins and 3,285 GeoShapes). I presume you've figured it out by now - but someone else might find this useful...

The following query returns the number of **CrimeLocations** in each **GeoShapes.ShapeFile**

```
SELECT G.Name, COUNT(CL.Id)
FROM   GeoShapes G
INNER JOIN CrimeLocations CL ON G.ShapeFile.STIntersects(CL.LatLong) = 1
GROUP BY G.Name
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

It takes *ages* (like 20 mins) because I haven't setup any geospatial indexes and my ShapeFiles have a high point-count, but it does run successfully. If I wanted to restrict the results as you suggest:

```
SELECT G.Name, COUNT(CL.Id)
FROM   GeoShapes G
INNER JOIN CrimeLocations CL ON G.ShapeFile.STIntersects(CL.LatLong) = 1
GROUP BY G.Name
HAVING COUNT(CL.Id) = 500
```

Of course you don't want to hardcode the number 500 - so you could add a `COUNT(*) FROM CrimeLocations` subquery there, or a variable with the total from a separate query.

Is that complex enough?

Comment: That's fine :) I ended up figuring it out a while back which basically is what i've done. cheers mate!

Comment: Glad you figured it out. I noticed how old the question was, but figured it was worth an answer for others with the same problem... the great thing about the spatial functions is that once you get your head around them, they make it easy to do some pretty complex stuff.