# Why are foreign keys more used in theory than in practice?

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys

When you study relational theory foreign keys are mandatory. But in practice, in every place I worked, table products and joins are always done by specifying the keys explicitly in the query, instead of relying on foreign keys in the DBMS.

This way, you could join two tables by fields that are not meant to be foreign keys, having unexpected results.

Why is that?

Shouldn't DBMSs enforce that Joins and Products be made only by foreign keys?

The main reason for FKs is reference integrity. But if you design a DB, relationships in the model (arrows in the ERD) become foreign keys. (N:M relationships become separate tables.) Whether or not you define them as such in your DBMS, they're semantically FKs.

I can't imagine the need to join tables by fields that aren't FKs; what is an example?

Comment: Referential integrity rules are not a 1 to 1 relationship with what should be allowed for joins.  Apples and oranges.

Comment: You misunderstand what foreign keys are intended for.  Joining on non-key columns is very useful in the real world.

Comment: Tables (bases & query results) represent relationships/associations. FKs are (ubiquitously) wrongly called "relationships". FKs & other constraints are not needed to query. They are facts re every business situation & its DB state. They stop some invalid updates & allow some optimizations. A query returns appropriately related rows regardless of the cardinalities of certain associated binary relationships. Owns NATURAL JOIN Animal returns (o,a,n) rows where o owns a & animal a has name n whether or not Owns or Animal is 1:M or M:1 or 1:1 or all animals are owned or people own only animals etc.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**The reason foreign key constraints exist is to guarantee that the referenced rows exist.**

"The foreign key identifies a column or a set of columns in one table that refers to a column or set of columns in another table. The values in one row of the referencing columns must occur in a single row in the referenced table.

Thus, a row in the referencing table cannot contain values that don't exist in the referenced table (except potentially NULL). This way references can be made to link information together and it is an essential part of database normalization." ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Foreign_key&oldid=327869194))

---

**RE: Your question: "I can't imagine the need to join tables by fields that aren't FKs":**

When defining a Foreign Key constraint, the column(s) in the referencing table must be the primary key of the referenced table, or at least a candidate key.

When doing joins, there is no need to join with primary keys or candidate keys.

The following is an example that could make sense:

```
CREATE TABLE clients (
    client_id       uniqueidentifier  NOT NULL,
    client_name     nvarchar(250)     NOT NULL,
    client_country  char(2)           NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE suppliers (
    supplier_id       uniqueidentifier  NOT NULL,
    supplier_name     nvarchar(250)     NOT NULL,
    supplier_country  char(2)           NOT NULL
);
```

And then query as follows:

```
SELECT 
    client_name, supplier_name, client_country 
FROM 
    clients 
INNER JOIN
    suppliers ON (clients.client_country = suppliers.supplier_country)
ORDER BY
    client_country;
```

Another case where these joins make sense is in databases that offer geospatial features, like SQL Server 2008 or Postgres with PostGIS. You will be able to do queries like these:

```
SELECT
    state, electorate 
FROM 
    electorates 
INNER JOIN 
    postcodes on (postcodes.Location.STIntersects(electorates.Location) = 1);
```

Source: [ConceptDev - SQL Server 2008 Geography: STIntersects, STArea](http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2007/12/sql-server-2008-geography-stintersects.html)

You can see another similar geospatial example in the accepted answer to the post "[Sql 2008 query problem - which LatLong’s exists in a geography polygon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303927/)":

```
SELECT 
    G.Name, COUNT(CL.Id)
FROM
    GeoShapes G
INNER JOIN 
    CrimeLocations CL ON G.ShapeFile.STIntersects(CL.LatLong) = 1
GROUP BY 
    G.Name;
```

These are all valid SQL joins that have nothing to do with foreign keys and candidate keys, and can still be useful in practice.

Comment: Yes you are right. Although the country reference is in fact a foreign key to a theoretical country table omitted in your example.

Comment: Yes theoretically. But in practice, you may not need a table for countries. Instead of country, it could have been "post code".

Comment: @Petruza: Even if the `client_country` is a foreign key (to the countries table), it's certainly not a foreign key to the `supplier_country`.

Comment: `The values in one row of the referencing columns must occur in a single row in the referenced table.`. Is it fine if a given row is present in the parent and not in the child?

Answer (score 37):

Foreign keys have less to do with joins than with keeping database integrity. Proof of that is that you can join tables in any way you want, even in ways that don't necessarily make sense.

Comment: Are you saying I shouldn't try to `SELECT * FROM book INNER JOIN person ON book.ISBN = person.Phone` ?

Comment: If that's what you need, by all means do it. You can even establish a FK between book.ISBN and person.Phone if your business requirements dictate it.

Comment: @R.Bemrose: That query is valid SQL, although does it make sense? is it useful for a system? I do think that you shouldn't try that.

Comment: @Petruza, foreign keys shouldn't be a replacement for good coding practices (e.g. code reviews), a DBMS software shouldn't restrict the expressiveness of the SQL language...otherwise we'd eventually get to the point where SQL Server would have the dreaded paperclip : "It looks like you're writing a query..." !

Comment: `select * from book as b inner join disc as d on b.num_sold = d.num_sold` - a join *sans* foreign keys.

Comment: @Powerlord I think you should try it. Just do it in a development sandbox, not production code :-)

Comment: If you have ad hoc inserts, updates, and deletes occuring over a significant amount of time (inversely related to frequency), and those ad hoc statements are done by lazy, unknowledgeable, or malicious devs, you'll do youself a heep of good by building some FKs, and don't forget the ON DELETE part.

Answer (score 10):

> I can't imagine the need to join tables by fields that aren't FKs. Can someone give an example that makes sense?

`FOREIGN KEY`s can only be used to enforce referential integrity if the relationship between the entities of the `ER` model is reflected with an equijoin between two relations in the relational model.

This is not always true.

Here's an example from the article in my blog I wrote some time ago:

- [**What is entity-relationship model?**](http://explainextended.com/2009/10/18/what-is-entity-relationship-model/)

This model describes goods and price ranges:

[image]

And here's the relational implementation of the model:

```
CREATE TABLE Goods (ID, Name, Price)
CREATE TABLE PriceRange (Price, Bonus)
```

As you can see, the `PriceRange` table has only one price-related attribute, `Price`, but the model has two attributes: `StartPrice` and `EndPrice`.

This is because relational model allows transforming the sets and the entity `PriceRange` can be easily reconstructed using `SQL` operations.

```
Goods
ID  Name               Price
1   Wormy apple        0.09
2   Bangkok durian     9.99
3   Densuke watermelon 999.99
4   White truffle      99999.99

PriceRange
Price   Bonus
0.01       1%
1.00       3%
100.00    10%
10000.00  30%
```

We store only the lower bound of each range. Upper bound can easily be inferred.

Here's the query to find the bonus for each good:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Goods
JOIN    PriceRange
ON      PriceRange.Price =
        (
        SELECT  MAX(Price)
        FROM    PriceRange
        WHERE   PriceRange.Price <= Goods.Price
        )
```

We see that these relational model implements the ER model fairly well, but no foreign key can be declared between these relations, since the operation used to bind them is not an equijoin.

Answer (score 9):

You can join on any expression.  Whether you define foreign keys in your database or not is immaterial.  Foreign keys constrain INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE, not SELECT.

So why do lots of projects skip defining foreign keys?  There are several reasons:

- The data model is designed poorly and requires broken references (examples: polymorphic associations, EAV).
- The coders may have heard that "foreign keys are slow" so they drop them.  In fact, the extra work you have to do to ensure data consistency when you can't rely on foreign keys makes your app much less efficient.  Premature optimization without actually measuring the benefit is a common problem.
- Constraints get in the way of some data cleanup tasks.  Sometimes you need to break references temporarily as you refactor data.  Many RDBMS allow constraints to be disabled, but sometimes the programmers decide it's easier to *leave* them disabled.  If there's a frequent need for disabling the constraints, this probably indicates a seriously broken database design.

Comment: there are some optimisations the query engine can make if it knows certain constraints are in place and can be trusted, so a constraint (foreign key, check) can affect SELECTs as well. Eg (SQL Server specific) http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2007/03/29/can-you-trust-your-constraints.aspx

Comment: @Remus: Thanks, that's good information about the optimization.  But what I meant was that you're not *prohibited* from joining on columns with no foreign key relationship.

Comment: `@Bill Karwin`: Actually, `FOREING KEY`s are slow in `Oracle` at least as of `10g` (due to the record-based way they're implemented). If you use a stored procedure as a single entry point to your tables and make all checks set-based before issuing `DML` operations, this is much faster in `Oracle`. `SQL Server`, on the other hand, does optimize `FOREING KEY`-implied `DML`.

Comment: Foreign key (and other) constraints can be used by the optimizer to improve performance on SELECTs, however - which is often free performance enhancement!

Comment: `@Cade Roux`: not in `Oracle`. But in `SQL Server`, definitely, yes. See here: http://explainextended.com/2009/10/15/constraints-and-the-optimizer-in-sql-server-foreign-key/

Comment: @Quassnoi: Thans, that's good information too.  More reasons why Oracle is a dinosaur that should be avoided.

Answer (score 8):

No, the enforcement is unnecessary; it would disallow some useful functionality, such as the possible overloading of columns.  While this sort of use isn't ideal, it IS useful in some real-world situations.

The appropriate use for Foreign key constraints is just as that; a constraint upon values added to a given column that assures that their referenced rows exist.

It should be noted that a significant lack of foreign key constraints on a given schema is a bad "smell", and can indicate some serious design problems.

Answer (score 5):

Because in practice, theory is not enough.

Theory is not flexible enough to consider all the possibilities that you have to handle in the real world. Only with one extremely bizarre case that you have to store in your DB (or something more common, like overloading columns) do you have to get out the FK and implement it in the data access layer (DAL).

Maybe you can develop some solution that can be archived in a totally normalized way, but in many cases the work needed and/or the final results are not worth it.

Comment: The consequences of theory cannot be avoided. The asker misunderstands the theory & practice. The theory says constraints need not be present, known or declared to query & query meanings & results are not affected by whether you declare a constraint that holds.

Answer (score 4):

Foreign keys used in the manner you describe is not how they are meant to be used.  They are meant to make sure that if a record logically depends on a corresponding record exist somewhere else, that that corresponding record is indeed there.

I believe that if developers/dbas have time to either (A) developer good names for their tables and fields, or (B) define extensive foreign key constraints, option **A** is the easy choice.  I've worked in both situations.  Where extensive constraints were relied upon to maintain order and keep people from screwing up things can really become a mess.

It takes a lot of effort to keep all your foreign key constraints up to date during development, time you could be spending on other high-value tasks that you barely have time for.  In contrast, in situations where you have good naming conventions, the foreign keys are instantly clear.  Developers don't have to look up foreign keys, or try a query to see if it works; they can just see the relationships.

I think foreign key constraints quickly become helpful as the number of different teams grow using a database grows.  It becomes difficult to enforce consistent naming; knowledge of the DB becomes fragmented; it's easy for db actions to have unintended consequences for another team.

Comment: But without constraints, you can never be sure that the data satisfies referential integrity, so you have to waste time running queries to search for duplicates or orphans.

Comment: Yes, that is the advantage that constraints give you.  (1) As with any good practice, evaluate how important it is in the particular situation.  (2) Balance the ROI of doing this good practice compared to the others, with limited time.  (3) Consider whether the good practice in question, despite any advantages it brings, can be a **crutch** that allows the developers to think they can **avoid** other good practices, which might actually be more important.  In multiple instances I've seen good DB design/nomenclature take 2nd place to constraints.  Disaster.  The reverse, usually not as bad.

Answer (score 3):

I've been programming for a couple decades, since well before relational databases became the norm.  When I first started working with MySQL when I taught myself PHP, I saw the foreign key option and my very first thought was "Wow!  That's retarded."  The reason be only a fool believes that the laboratory dictates reality.  It was obvious immediately that unless you were coding an application that would never, *ever*, be changed, you're wrapping your application in a steel cast where the only option is to either build more tables or come up with creative solutions.

This initial assessment has been born out in every single real-world production application I have come across.  Not only do the constraints significantly slow down any and all modifications, they make the growing of the application almost impossible, something that is required for a business.

The only reason I've ever found for any constraints on a table is lazy coders not willing to write clean code to check data integrity.

Answer (score 2):

DBMS's are built to allow the widest number of solutions while still working according to their core rules.

Restricting joins to defined foreign keys would limit functionality enormously, especially as most development does not occur with a dedicated DBA or review of SQL/stored procedures.

Having said that, depending on your Data Access Layer, you may be required to configure foreign keys, to use functionality. For example Linq to SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Foreign keys are not used as often as relational theory suggests because DB/relational type people don't write much of the code or even design the tables. Programmers write the code/design tables or have much influence on how the tables are designed.

Comment: An IT professional should know relational theory AND programming, being a programmer shouldn't be an excuse for being a lousy DB designer.

Answer (score 2):

What sort of database applications do you work on?  The theory that you frequently see is about using the database raw, in which case constraints can be very useful.  In practice, databases are often used as the back end of larger applications.  In many cases, these applications have to validate transactions themselves, and it would be wasted effort to repeat it in the database.

Consider a sales application, for example.  When somebody's entering an order, it will perhaps look up the customer in the database, to get the address or credit card information.  When it doesn't find a customer, it will be programmed to do something reasonable.  If it waited until it tried to insert a row into the order table to discover there was no customer, it would get slower and less convenient feedback.

Something has to maintain the integrity of the database, but doing it inside the DBMS itself is not always the best way.

Answer (score 1):

Foreign keys are extremely important, especially in databases that have manual queries run upon them, or are having software actively developed for them. Every untested query that is run on the database has the possibility of containing an error. Constraints such as foreign keys serve to highlight these errors before inconsistency is introduced into the data.

These constraints are applied by the designer of the schema, and they ensure that the data remains in the model that (s)he envisaged. If the constraints are not there, then sooner or later a query will introduce some inconsistency. Inconsistency will lead to unpredictable results from queries, and is very hard to reverse.

Answer (score 0):

I have always wondered why SQL doesn't have a syntax like

```
SELECT tbl1.col1, tbl2.col2
  FROM tbl1
  JOIN tbl2 USING (FK_tbl1_tbl2)
```

where `FK_tbl1_tbl2` is some foreign key constraint between the tables. This would be incredibly more useful than `NATURAL JOIN` or Oracle's `USING (col1, col2)`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to set them up without a query in most MySQL GUI tools (Navicat, MySQL, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Part of it is that the UI in MS's SQL Server Management studio for adding foreign keys is **awful**.

A foreign key is a constraint that "any value in column x on table a must appear in column y on table b", but the UI for specifying it in SSMS doesn't clearly indicate which table you're messing with, which is the parent table, which is the child table, and so on.

Every time I've had to create a foreign key, it's been trial and error until it seemed to work.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not aware of a SQL dialect which automatically joins all foreign key tables implicitly.  I've seen code generation and data dictionary tools for reporting infer them, but the SQL is always explicit.

That's why you are seeing that, in practice, in SQL, **ALL** joins are explicit.

In practice, databases without FK constraints tend to have integrity issues, since there is no constraint to require the key to exist.  So it's certainly a best practice to have as many constraints as possible - it protects integrity and helps the optimizer and other users.  As with any best practice, knowing when (if ever) to break the rule is also important.

As to why you can make a join which doesn't match a foreign key constraint between those tables, there are myriad examples.  Particularly in the case of composite keys with partial joins, I find this is often necessary.  We often join on tables using partial versions of their primary keys in data warehousing.

You may also be interested in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2009/11/12/conor-vs-foreign-key-join-elimination.aspx) on foreign key join elimination by the optimizer.

Comment: Yes I know all products and joins are explicit, my english is limited, what I meant is they the fields used for the joins have no distinction from other fields, like being a FK, just their names (hopefully) resemble their meaning.

Comment: A column is a column is a column.  Naming is all basically user preference.  Constraints are what define the database in the metadata.  There are often tons of things not specified in constraints that are simply "known", but not explicit.  e.g. "There are never transactions with negative value in a certain GL code/cost center combination."  Many non-foreign key joins kind of fall into these categories.

Answer (score -2):

Foreign key is **coupling**. In programming, coupling is rarely good.