# why should i set foreign keys in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreign-keys

If I just have some foreign keys in my table and they dont set any constraints and I will not set any `CASCADE DELETE` , why should I set foreign keys like `FOREIGN KEY (a) REFERENCES b(c)` ?

What is the purpose of setting foreign keys if you dont wont to set cascade delete or update? Semantics? Makes the queries faster?

Thanks

Comment: If you use Innodb as storage engine it will automatically index foreign keys.

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907325/why-do-i-need-to-use-foreign-key-if-i-can-use-where

Comment: Basically, to enforce data integrity. You don't want orders for unknown customers, just like you don't want dates like `31st Feb` or numbers like `Yellow`.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key actually does not help performance but cost a little more instead since it has to force the constraint.

It is there for data integrity and to prevent destructive write.  more important as the database grows

Comment: Edit this `It is there to prevent destructive write and data integrity` to this `It is there for data integrity and to prevent destructive write`. As is right now sounds like it is there to prevent both destructive write and data integrity. Other than that, thank you for your answer.