# Why use Foreign Key constraints in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, foreign-keys

I was wondering,

What will be my motivation to use constraint as foreign key in MySQL, as I am sure that I can rule the types that are added?

Does it improve performance?

Comment: similar question has been answered, see
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876013/ there are a lot of discussions :D

Answer (score 77, accepted):

[Foreign keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) enforce [referential integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity). These constraints guarantee that a row in a table `order_details` with a field `order_id` referencing an `orders` table will never have an `order_id` value that doesn't exist in the `orders` table.

Foreign keys aren't required to have a working relational database (in fact [MySQL's default storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MyISAM) engine doesn't support FKs), but they are definitely essential to avoid broken relationships and orphan rows (ie. referential integrity). The ability to enforce referential integrity at the database level is required for the *C* in [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) to stand.

As for your concerns regarding performance, in general there's a performance cost, but will probably be negligible. I suggest putting in all your foreign key constraints, and only experiment without them if you have real performance issues that you cannot solve otherwise.

Comment: Is there any good reasons why NOT to use foreign key constraints? I have worked on various php frameworks and have never needed to use them. I feel like the application should be the one handling and preventing the orphans. Could some one enlighten me?

Comment: @AngelS.Moreno: It's a bit like asking "Is there any reason not to use a garbage collector?". Just that in this case, you won't gain performance by managing this kind of DB garbage yourself. Quite the contrary. Issuing all queries required to keep FK relations consistent is not only extremely error prone, it is also extremely inefficient.

Comment: The only good reason not to use FK is when you don't need consistency.

Comment: Yes, there ARE good reasons for not using FK constraints. The most obvious one in my mind is that you can end up locking several rows at once which can have unintended consequences. We've inadvertently done this here and we often find our database slow and totally frozen up for certain records. Please read this article: https://www.percona.com/blog/2010/10/25/impact-of-the-sort-buffer-size-in-mysql/

Comment: Another one is difficulty if you ever want to rename the table https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384778/renaming-an-innodb-table-without-updating-foreign-key-references-to-it

Answer (score 0):

One reason is that a set of tables with foreign key constraints cannot be sharded into multiple databases.