# MySQL multiple-table delete syntax

Tags: mysql

I try to do 2 delete queries in one. For example:

```
DELETE FROM `comments` WHERE `article_id` = 4;
DELETE FROM `aricles` WHERE `id` = 4;
```

I tried using a single query:

```
DELETE `articles`, `comments` 
FROM `articles` INNER JOIN `comments` 
WHERE `comments`.`article_id` = `articles`.`id` AND `articles`.`id` = 4
```

That works well if in table `comments` exist records with `article_id` 4, but doesn't remove `articles` records with `articles`.`id` = 4, if in `comments` records with `article_id` = 4 not found. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: you really should take a look on constraints. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433975/why-use-foreign-key-constraints-in-mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do it -

```
DELETE `articles`, `comments`
FROM `articles`
LEFT JOIN `comments`
    ON `articles`.`id` = `comments`.`article_id`
WHERE `articles`.`id` = 4;
```

Comment: This will also delete `articles` that have no `comments`. This answers the question more exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
DELETE FROM `articles`, `comments` 
USING `articles` INNER JOIN `comments` 
WHERE `comments`.`article_id` = `articles`.`id` AND `articles`.`id` = 4
```

Comment: This will *not* delete `articles` that have no `comments`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
DELETE FROM `articles`, `comments` 
USING `articles`,`comments` 
WHERE `comments`.`article_id` = `articles`.`id` AND `articles`.`id` = 4
```

or

```
DELETE `articles`, `comments` 
FROM `articles`, `comments` 
WHERE `comments`.`article_id` = `articles`.`id` AND `articles`.`id` = 4
```