# Foreign Key advantage when not using ondelete or onupdate

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreign-keys, rdbms

What is the advantage of having a `foreign key relationship` if I am not having any `delete or update constraints` set?

Suppose I have a table for items that users can post for reselling.

```
item_id  item_product_id   item_title            other_fields
1        1                 New TV for sale       ...
1        1                 Old TV for sale       ...
1        2                 Radio for sale        ...
```

And the product table would be:

```
product_id   product_name
1            TV
2            Radio
```

Now if a `product` is removed from the `product table`, I would not want the items to be deleted as well. The user can see that his item's product exists no longer and can select another closest appropriate product. So my question is - if this is the `structure and logic` I have, is there any advantage I get by linking the items and product tables using `foreign keys`?

Or, will I even be able to delete from products if there is a `foreign key` entry in items?

Comment: The only point to the key is to build an easy relationship between tables.  Affecting one won't affect the other unless you tell it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One advantage is that your RDMS won't let you insert invalid data to begin with.  If there is no product with ID 5, then you will be absolutely unable to create an item for it (whether from a script *or* from the mysql command line).  This goes under the heading of data integrity.

Also, it might be worthwhile for you to checkout [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3433975/697370)

Answer (score 0):

> Or, will I even be able to delete from products if there is a foreign key entry in items?

No, you won't, unless you specify `ON DELETE CASCADE` or `ON DELETE SET NULL`.

Neither you will be able to insert into `items` unless you have a matching record in `products`.

Comment: @UndefinedVariable: can't tell. "What's better" questions do not really belong here, I answered the only question which was in the scope of this site.