# Foreign key doesn't get auto_incremented

Tags: php, mysql

**My Code:**

[image]

```
    create table Products
(
    ProductID int not null auto_increment primary key,
    ProductName varchar(20),
    Recommendedprice decimal(10,2),
    Category varchar(10)

)



create table customers
(
    CustomerID int not null auto_increment primary key,
    FirstName varchar(50),
    LastName varchar(50),
    city varchar(50),
    State char(2),
    zip varchar(10)

)


    create table sales
    (
        SalesID int not null auto_increment primary key,
        ProductID int, 
        CustomerID int,
        CONSTRAINT fk_PerProducts FOREIGN KEY (ProductId)
        REFERENCES Products(ProductId),  
        CONSTRAINT fk_PerCustomers FOREIGN KEY (CustomerId)
        REFERENCES customers(customerId),  
        SalesPrice decimal(10,2),
        SalesDate date 
    )
```

I get null values in the table list.

Comment: create database practice create table Products
(
    ProductID int not null auto_increment primary key,
    ProductName varchar(20),
    Recommendedprice decimal(10,2),
    Category varchar(10)
    
)   create table customers
(
    CustomerID int not null auto_increment primary key,
    FirstName varchar(50),
    LastName varchar(50),
    city varchar(50),
    State char(2),
    zip varchar(10)
    
)

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: what was the query? do you `left join` tables?

Comment: Is there someone who can help to get rid out from this ? :D

Comment: no....i used two foreign keys in create table statements only....there should be integer values but what i get is Null values....don't know why ? some modification required?    i am at beginner level !

Comment: while inserting data you have to insert the values, foreign key does not get automatically populated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the id of the foreigner key when you make an INSERT.

like this (`paper_Author` work like your `sales` table) :

```
CREATE TABLE Paper (`paperId` int, `title` varchar(7));
INSERT INTO Paper (`paperId`, `title`)
VALUES (1, 'hello'),(2, 'hola'),(3, 'bonjour');

CREATE TABLE Author (`authorId` int, `authorName` varchar(3));
INSERT INTO Author (`authorId`, `authorName`)
VALUES (1, 'me'),(2, 'moi');

CREATE TABLE Paper_Author (`paperId` int, `authorId` int);
INSERT INTO Paper_Author (`paperId`, `authorId`)
VALUES (1, 1),(1, 2),(2, 2);
```

and you use it like this : 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb61f/2

---

other think you should read :

[Basics of Foreign Keys in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757181/basics-of-foreign-keys-in-mysql)

[Why use Foreign Key constraints in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433975/why-use-foreign-key-constraints-in-mysql)

Comment: so the conclusion is : i must insert the value of foreign key by myself. It will not come from primary table ?

Comment: yes if i insert manually It works. Thanks. I thought it will come from primary but that's not true.I guess !

Comment: your code can't guess what you want to link. the `id` primary key is here to be a unique identifier you can use in other table to reference as the whole row (like a flash code on a product). The constraint if used on `innoDB` mySql DB will lock the row if you still have a children that belong to it. This allow you to keep you data integrity (no orphan).

Comment: i understood my mistake. i didn't see the sales table clearly. so i was stucked in a wrong way. At last i got rid of it. Thanks to stackoverflow ! and all of  you guys for your responses !