# Why is a primary-foreign key relation required when we can join without them?

Tags: sql, database

Why is a primary-foreign key relation required when we can join without them?

```
test1 (id, lname, fname, dob)
-- no primary and foreign key and not unique
-- (no constraints)

test2 (id, native_city)
-- no relations and no constraints
```

I can still join these tables with column `id`.

Comment: Please post your table structure - it will make explaining much easier.

Comment: PKs, UNIQUEs, NOT NULLs & FKs have nothing to do with querying. They are integrity constraints.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are foreign keys more used in theory than in practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876013/why-are-foreign-keys-more-used-in-theory-than-in-practice)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The main reason for primary and foreign keys is to enforce data consistency.

A primary key enforces the consistency of uniqueness of values over one or more columns.  If an ID column has a primary key then it is impossible to have two rows with the same ID value. Without that primary key, many rows could have the same ID value and you wouldn't be able to distinguish between them based on the ID value alone.

A foreign key enforces the consistency of data that points elsewhere. It ensures that the data which is pointed to actually exists. In a typical parent-child relationship, a foreign key ensures that every child always points at a parent and that the parent actually exists. Without the foreign key you could have "orphaned" children that point at a parent that doesn't exist.

Comment: can you pls give practicle example?

Comment: without primary id test1 could have 

    '''
    id:1234 lname:wade fname:ka dob:1/1/1903
    id:1234 lname:someone fname:elseWithSameID dob:1/1/1995
    id:1234 lname:wade fname:ka dob:1/1/2016 // same person with two different records

Comment: without foreign key, test1 could have id:1 lname:Renshaw  id:3 lname:kawade. While test2 could have id:1 Brooklyn id:2 Far-Rockaway id:3 Montreal.  This would be inconsistent because there is no test1 record with Id of 2. Defining the foreign key in SQL makes it so that you cannot create a test2 record with id 2, if id of value 2 does not exist in test1 as well. Also it does not let you delete a record in test1 with id value of 3 if a record with id of value 3 exists in test2.

Comment: This does not answers the question. The answer is yes, you can. The consequences are other issue.

Answer (score 23):

You need two columns of the same type, one on each table, to JOIN on.  Whether they're primary and foreign keys or not doesn't matter.

Comment: Wouldn't they only need to be the same type in the JOIN expression i.e. A casting and JOINing on the results would be fine too?

Comment: Primary and foreign keys are about normalization and referential integrity first, JOIN second.  If you don't know why you need a primary key for every row in a table, then you shouldn't be using relational databases.

Answer (score 23):

You don't need a FK, you can join arbitrary columns.

But having a foreign key ensures that the join will actually succeed in finding something.

Foreign key give you certain guarantees that would be extremely difficult and error prone to implement otherwise.

For example, if you don't have a foreign key, you might insert a detail record in the system and just after you checked that the matching master record is present somebody else deletes it. So in order to prevent this you need to lock the master table, when ever you modify the detail table (and vice versa). If you don't need/want that guarantee, screw the FKs.

Depending on your RDBMS a foreign key also might improve performance of select (but also degrades performance of updates, inserts and deletes)

Comment: @Jona "But having a foreign key ensures that the join will actually succeed in finding something" is misleading. Constraints are not needed to query, they don't affect query meanings & declaring them does not change what would be returned in a correct DB state. If you could declare a FK then the query returns the same value from a correct DB state whether you declare it or not. A FK constraint says that in this DB when a certain subrow of values participates in a relation(ship)/association it participates in a certain other one once. Constraints are for disallowing incorrect DB states.

Comment: Note that referencing columns defined as `NOT NULL`  are needed to guarantee success in finding something.

Answer (score 7):

I know its late to post, but I use the site for my own reference and so I wanted to put an answer here for myself to reference in the future too. I hope you (and others) find it helpful.

Lets pretend a bunch of super Einstein experts designed our database. Our super perfect database has 3 tables, and the following relationships defined between them:

```
TblA 1:M TblB
TblB 1:M TblC

Notice there is no relationship between TblA and TblC
```

In most scenarios such a simple database is easy to navigate but in commercial databases it is usually impossible to be able to tell at the design stage all the possible uses and combination of uses for data, tables, and even whole databases, especially as systems get built upon and other systems get integrated or switched around or out. This simple fact has spawned a whole industry built on top of databases called Business Intelligence. But I digress...

In the above case, the structure is so simple to understand that its easy to see you can join from TblA, through to B, and through to C and vice versa to get at what you need. It also very vaguely highlights some of the problems with doing it. Now expand this simple chain to 10 or 20 or 50 relationships long. Now all of a sudden you start to envision a need for exactly your scenario. In simple terms, a join from A to C or vice versa or A to F or B to Z or whatever as our system grows.

There are many ways this can indeed be done. The one mentioned above being the most popular, that is driving through all the links. The major problem is that its very slow. And gets progressively slower the more tables you add to the chain, the more those tables grow, and the further you want to go through it.

Solution 1: Look for a common link. It must be there if you taught of a reason to join A to C. If it is not obvious, create a relationship and then join on it. i.e. To join A through B through C there must be some commonality or your join would either produce zero results or a massive number or results (Cartesian product). If you know this commonality, simply add the needed columns to A and C and link them directly.

The rule for relationships is that they simply must have a reason to exist. Nothing more. If you can find a good reason to link from A to C then do it. But you must ensure your reason is not redundant (i.e. its already handled in some other way).

Now a word of warning. There are some pitfalls. But I don't do a good job of explaining them so I will refer you to [my source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YKqJ_FjfyVM) instead of talking about it here. But remember, this is getting into some heavy stuff, so this video about fan and chasm traps is really only a starting point. You can join without relationships. But I advise watching this video first as this goes beyond what most people learn in college and well into the territory of the BI and SAP guys. These guys, while they can program, their day job is to specialise in exactly this kind of thing. How to get massive amounts of data to talk to each other and make sense.

This video is one of the better videos I have come across on the subject. And it's worth looking over some of his other videos. I learned a lot from him.

Comment: Here is a concise precise summary subsuming your post: Given tables representing relation(ship)s/associations, their natural join represents the conjunction/AND of their relation(ship)s/associations. Fan & chasm "traps" occur when people expect otherwise. Constraints (including PKs, CKs, superkeys/UNIQUEs, FKs & cardinalities) are neither needed nor sufficient to query. Adding columns to a table via natural joins requires appropriate conjoining/ANDing to get the new relation(ship)/association represented.

Answer (score 3):

A primary key is not required. A foreign key is not required either. You can construct a query joining two tables on any column you wish as long as the datatypes either match or are converted to match. No relationship needs to explicitly exist.

To do this you use an outer join:

```
select tablea.code, tablea.name, tableb.location from tablea left outer join 
tableb on tablea.code = tableb.code
```

[join with out relation](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/answer/Joining-tables-without-a-primary-key)

[SQL join](https://coderanch.com/t/464102/databases/Table-Join-Foreign-Key)