# how to combine 2 or more tables without PK

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been trying to combine without success using UNIONS and JOINS 4 tables. 
Each of this tables has just one column and 2 rows and they don't have anything in common. I am trying to create 1 Table that combines them all with all rows aligned.

```
Example:
Table 1
vegetables
Potato  
Tomato 

Table 2
Utilities
Knife
Pan

Table 3
Fruits
Orange
Apple

Table 4
Liquids
Wine
Water

Final Table:

vegetables  Utilities  Fruits   Liquids
Potato      Knife      Orange   wine 
Tomato      Pan        Apple    Water
```

Sorry for the weird names, and if this has already been asked.
I tried several examples i found around but most of them use a common key to filter, but as the tables have nothing When I tried this examples I ended up with a table with 8 Rows 
The tables also can variate in amount of rows from 1 to 10, but they if one has 10 they all do.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I am using SQL server Express 2012

Comment: ??? I think you missed the point of a database table... the schema you have in the beginning seems much better than the one you're trying to get

Comment: Its actually for a stored procedure that combines 4 tables into one.

Comment: i think its not possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771190/can-we-join-two-tables-without-primary-foreign-key-relation

Comment: @Dante Snow : yet I don't see the point... but Devart's answer here under should help. But Devart's answer here under should help I think.  But once again you may be heading to a wrong direction...

Comment: @Bartdude Let me explain it clearer, I have a physical address Direction that must be composed by a street, a door number, a corner street and a Type of address( a office, home, etc). the direction is associated to another table, witch contains the name of the Organization and other info. because one organization can have several addresses all of the rows fields are passed in a long string that separates each field with a coma, then a function makes a table  from this long string separating each value. then I end up with the 4 talbes Sorry if its hard to understand me.

Comment: I don't understand everything you say indeed, what I know is that the schema of the final table you're asking is not a good schema... You would need the organizations in one table, the addresses in another (with the separate fields for street, number and so on) , with a primary key in each table, and a table in between to do the link, with an extra field indicating the type of address (home, office). that's to be short...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one -

**Query 1:**

```
DECLARE @temp1 TABLE (vegetables NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @temp1 (vegetables)
VALUES ('Potato'), ('Tomato')

DECLARE @temp2 TABLE (Utilities NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @temp2 (Utilities)
VALUES ('Knife'), ('Pan')

DECLARE @temp4 TABLE (Liquids NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @temp4 (Liquids)
VALUES ('Wine'), ('Water')

DECLARE @temp3 TABLE (Fruits NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @temp3 (Fruits)
VALUES ('Orange'), ('Apple')

SELECT t1.vegetables, t2.Utilities, t3.Fruits, t4.Liquids
FROM (
    SELECT t.vegetables, id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) 
    FROM @temp1 t
) t1
JOIN (
    SELECT t.Utilities, id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) 
    FROM @temp2 t
) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
JOIN (
    SELECT t.Fruits, id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) 
    FROM @temp3 t
) t3 ON t1.id = t3.id
JOIN (
    SELECT t.Liquids, id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) 
    FROM @temp4 t
) t4 ON t1.id = t4.id
```

**Output 1:**

```
vegetables  Utilities  Fruits   Liquids
----------- ---------- -------- ---------
Potato      Knife      Wine     Orange
Tomato      Pan        Water    Apple
```

**Query 2** (possible answer for you comment)**:**

```
SELECT t1.vegetables, t2.Utilities, t3.Fruits, t4.Liquids
FROM @temp1 t1
CROSS JOIN @temp2 t2
CROSS JOIN @temp3 t3
CROSS JOIN @temp4 t4
```

**Output 2:**

```
vegetables   Utilities  Fruits    Liquids
------------ ---------- --------- -------
Potato       Knife      Wine      Orange
Potato       Knife      Apple     Orange
Potato       Knife      Wine      Water
Potato       Knife      Apple     Water
Tomato       Knife      Wine      Orange
Tomato       Knife      Apple     Orange
Tomato       Knife      Wine      Water
Tomato       Knife      Apple     Water
Potato       Pan        Wine      Orange
Potato       Pan        Apple     Orange
Potato       Pan        Wine      Water
Potato       Pan        Apple     Water
Tomato       Pan        Wine      Orange
Tomato       Pan        Apple     Orange
Tomato       Pan        Wine      Water
Tomato       Pan        Apple     Water
```