# SQL select statement which maps a value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. 
- Table 1 includes (ID, Name, gender, interestsID)
- Table 2 includes (ID, interests).

Now I want to have a new SELECT statement which show me instead of the interestsID the name behind that ID which is of course in an another table. So basically a mapping must be done and reflect the correct value behind the ID.

Comment: Use `join` to do the mapping.

Comment: Are you talking about joins?  If so, have a read of [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/)?

Comment: Just learn SQL JOIN ;) have a look https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208854(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Use `join` but also it is there should be a relationship between `interestsID` of `Includes` table and `ID` of `interests` table. i.e a `Primary Key` and `Foreign Key`

Comment: @Rohit are you trying to say that he can't use the join if there is no relation between these two tables..? really..?

Comment: @Sachin he can but most efficient way is with relationship of keys. Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771190/can-we-join-two-tables-without-primary-foreign-key-relation

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the two tables using I.D. The below code should work assuming your tables are actually called Table1 and Table2.

```
SELECT  Table1.Name
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.ID =Table2.ID;
```

In order to understand joins you should refer to this link http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp.