# Foreign key is needed for inner join in SQL?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, inner-join

```
INSERT INTO customers (ID, NAME, AGE, ADDRESS, SALARY)
VALUES(3, 'sin', 21, 'bangalore', 10000);

INSERT INTO orders (orderid, orderno)
VALUES (3, 21);
```

Here `ID` is the primary key in the `customer` table, `orderid` is the primary key in the `orders` table.

I would like to know whether it is mandatory to add `id` as foreign key in `orders` table for performing SQL join?

Comment: The answer is NO... you can do an sql join on anything as long as it is correctly cast to the same type. It may not provide you with good performance as SQL foreign key comes with performance benefits.

Comment: A declared foreign key relationship is not necessary for using `join`.

Comment: [Foreign keys are not needed to join tables!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/266284)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is a primary-foreign key relation required when we can join without it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771190/why-is-a-primary-foreign-key-relation-required-when-we-can-join-without-it)

Answer (score 4):

It is not necessary to establish a foreign key in order to perform an inner join of the customers and orders table. However, the question arises of what the significance of such a join operation would be without a foreign key.

Presumably the goal is to model some sort of relationship between customers and orders. Assuming the attributes listed comprise all of the attributes in the two tables, there is nothing establishing a relationship between customers and orders in the way the tables are defined. Adding a customerID field as a foreign key in the orders table would establish that relationship. Then, an inner join on the condition customers.ID = orders.customerID would associate the order information with the appropriate customer's information in the joined table.

Comment: nice explanation,since i am new to this sql had a confusion, that whether it is mandatory. thank you so much.

Comment: A RM (relational model) table represents a relation/relationship/association. A join holds the rows of values that participate in both inputs' relationships. Eg owns(owner,pet) join eats(pet,food) returns rows where [owner] owns [pet] & [pet] eats [food], period. FKs get wrongly called relationships but are truths. When a SQL FK holds it just means that if a certain subrow participates in a certain relationship then it participates in a certain other's, once. (Input constraints do imply output constraints.) [FKs are not needed to join tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/266284)

Answer (score 3):

My thought here that when you asking whether FK is needed or not, you accept by default that both working within the same domain, and this is not a valid assumption, in brief

> The **inner join** is used with the reading (query) of data, whereas **FK**
>   exists to maintain the integrity of data during a different kind of operations such as insert, update and delete.

In my opinion, the correct answer should be that **both FK and inner join are not relevant**.

I will use the below tables to explain the difference between both

```
Customers 
| id          | name     | 
|:------------|---------:|
| 1           |  Gabriel |
| 2           |  John    | 
| 3           |  Smith   | 


Orders 
| order_id   |customer_id| 
|:-----------|---------: |
| 1          |  1        |
| 2          |  1        | 
| 3          |  1        | 
| 4          |  2        |
```

**Inner Join**,

is used during **query** for example according to the above, let's say you want to query all orders made by a specific customer.

```
select * from customers, orders
where customer.id=orders.customer_id
and customer.id=2
```

according to our tables, you will end up with one order number (4) for the customer (John)

**Foreign Key**

While the **inner join** used during the query, the **Foreign Key** is used to apply policies over the major DML operations (Insert, update and delete).

below are examples of operations that will fail for violating the FK constraint

```
Insert into orders(order_id,customer_id) values(5,7)
```

this operation will fail because no customer exists with id (7) in the Customer table, the same will apply for the update operation.

Also if the FK enabled the **On delete cascade** or **On update cascade**
this will delete or update child rows when trying to delete or update the master table, example deleting the customer Gabriel will delete orders 1,2 and 3.

Comment: You are not answering the question. Read it. "Foreign key is needed for inner join in SQL?" "whether it is mandatory to add id as foreign key in orders table for performing SQL join?" (And the answer is, no.) PS See my other comments on this page.

Comment: @philipxy I believe maybe my first line was misleading, but if you read carefully through the answer you would conclude that **join** related to reading operation, while **Foreign Key** is a constraint on different kind of operations (insert, update and delete), according to this the FK not just not needed but also is not relevant. anyway, I will update the first line accordingly.

Comment: One could & might conclude it, but one might not, so you should spell it out. It would help if you dropped "difference" & lead with (extracting from your comment) "a FK is not just not needed but also is not relevant" since "join is a reading operation, while a Foreign Key is a constraint on other operations".

Comment: When you edit, just write the best presentation, don't just add EDITs or UPDATEs or refer to past versions or comments. PS "both work within the same domain" is too unclear when you haven't explained anything yet; and then you never tie what comes later to "same domain" so you never explain. See my last comment, which crossed yours & your edit. PS You mean more like, the correct answer should be that FKs and joins are not relevant to each other.