# Is there a foreign key alternative?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables `book` and `author`.

I need to insert a book where author `name` can **sometimes** be found in the author table.

Then I would like to query how many `book`s each author in the author table has.

Can we have a key relationship between these two tables? Or should we just query the number of books per author with a join query?

I doubt that a foreign key can help me here as not all authors in the book table are present in the author table.

Should I go with two separate table with no link between them?

Comment: Foreign key does not help you query, foreign key helps you store. You can join tables regardless of foreign keys. If you don't have the data to satisfy the foreign key, then you cannot have the foreign key, there is no choice.

Comment: What are you you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Kevin what i am trying to achieve is to have a fixed number of authors in the author table then insert books on the go and be able to query how much book do the authors in author table have.

Comment: you would probably want an intermediary table which holds the primary keys of each table as a foreign key to allow the linking of the two elements together.

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question? Please clarify via edits, not comments. [mre] [ask] [Help]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is a primary-foreign key relation required when we can join without it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771190/why-is-a-primary-foreign-key-relation-required-when-we-can-join-without-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foreign key is not about querying data. It's help to store data consistent.
In your case when you add foreign key on table books point to authors table you strict insertion books where author not exists on foreign table and prevent delete author when his books presents in books table.

In real case one book can have many co-authors, so you should implement many-to-many relationship, using third table

```
create table books (id int primary key, name varchar(64));

create table authors (id int primary key, name varchar(64));

create table books_authors (
    book_id int,
    author_id int,
    primary key (book_id, author_id),
    constraint fx_book_id foreign key (book_id) references books(id),
    constraint fx_author_id foreign key (author_id) references authors(id)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [Slava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74043256/361842) as being the best approach.

Should you have a case where you wanted only 0 or 1 items related though (i.e. if you required that every book have only one author) you can do that with a foreign key in the book table pointing at the author table. To allow this to be optional, just allow that value to be null (i.e. it is by default if you don't include `not null` in that field's statement).

```sql
create table author (
  id bigint not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered
  , name nvarchar(256) not null
)

create table book (
  id bigint not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered
  , title nvarchar(256) not null
  , authorId bigint foreign key references author(id)
)
```

To query this you'd then do

```sql
select * 
from book b
left outer join author a
on a.id = b.authorId
```

Or for all books by a certain author:

```sql
select * 
from book b
inner join author a
on a.id = b.authorId
where a.name = 'Skeet, Jon'
```