# How do I "link" two tables when the primary key of table_a could exist in none, one or many columns in table_b?

Tags: postgresql, email, database-design, relational-database, datamodel

How do I link two tables, `People` and `Messages`, when there is no single column in the `Messages` table that corresponds to the primary key of the `People` table?

I have two tables: one containing email messages called `Messages` and one of people called `People`.

People

| person_id | email_address |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | `billy@gmail.com` |
| 002 | `bobby@gmail.com` |
| 003 | `gregg@gmail.com` |
| 004 | `janet@gmail.com` |
| 005 | `boss1@gmail.com` |

Messages

| msg_id | from_addr | to_addr | cc_addr | bcc_addr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | `billy@gmail.com` | `gregg@gmail.com`, `david@gmail.com` | `boss1@gmail.com` | NULL |
| 002 | `bobby@gmail.com` | `gregg@gmail.com` | NULL | NULL |
| 003 | `janet@gmail.com` | `boss1@gmail.com` | `bobby@gmail.com` | `gregg@gmail.com` |

I will be programmatically passed a `person_id` (say `005` for `boss1@gmail.com`) and want to be able to query the `Messages` dataset to get all "involved" emails--where a `boss1@gmail.com` was sent, received, was cc'd or bcc'd in the email message. So with the dataset above, the query ought to return the  rows with `msg_id` `001` and `003`.

I don't know to map the relation between the `People` and `Messages` tables.

Say the primary key of of the `People` table is `person_id`. There is no **single** column that I can link that to in the `Messages` table to act as a foreign key.

I cannot determine how to represent this data correctly.

Am I doing this wrong? What is a better way to represent these two tables with more tables structured differently?

After normalising to 1NF:

Messages_FNF

| msg_id | from_addr | to_addr | cc_addr | bcc_addr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | `billy@gmail.com` | `gregg@gmail.com` | `boss1@gmail.com` | NULL |
| 001 | `billy@gmail.com` | `david@gmail.com` | `boss1@gmail.com` | NULL |
| 002 | `bobby@gmail.com` | `gregg@gmail.com` | NULL | NULL |
| 003 | `janet@gmail.com` | `boss1@gmail.com` | `bobby@gmail.com` | `gregg@gmail.com` |

However, the  primary key (that uniquely identifies each row in the table) for `Messages_FNF` would have to be a composite key combining `msg_id`, `from_addr`, `to_addr`, `cc_addr`, `bcc_addr`.

So how do I [link](https://www.relationaldbdesign.com/database-design/module2/linking-relational-database-tables.php) the `People` and `Messages` tables together using Primary and Foreign keys?

Or must I further normalise or partition these tables such that the `People` table and `Messages_FNF` have a meaningful matching field - allowing for easy joins? If so, how?

I've read that the [cross join](https://learnsql.com/blog/join-tables-without-common-column/) lets you join tables that do not have a common field but I worry that it will result in a VERY large table with unnecessary rows and be computationally expensive.

Is linking the tables with a PK->FK the right way of structuring the data in this problem?

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question? [ask] [Help] [mre]

Comment: "Am I doing this wrong?" Yes: specifically `Messages` has repeating fields `to_addr`, `cc_addr` -- so it isn't a 'table'. You need first to restructure `Messages` to (at least) 'First Normal Form' -- which'll need 'vertical partitioning'.

Comment: Again: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question? PS Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts. Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. Please don't **Yell**. PS Yes or no questions are almost always poor questions & also are almost always not asking what is actually intended. PS It is unhelpful & unclear to ask 'A or B' when A & B are not mutually exclusive and/or not the only options. (And you may think they are when they are not.)

Comment: Thanks or the advice @philipxy. Here is some relevant research for the question:

Microsoft:ERD of an Email App
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8806881d-1091-4e49-905f-fe25a9268e63/erd-of-an-email-app?forum=transactsql

ReserchGate - ERD Diagram from Ayat Bu-Suhail et al. 2019
https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Entity-Relationship-Diagram_fig3_335541387

SO: "Best practice to store array-like data in MySQL or similar database?"
^Not helpful as arrays appear to be causing problems when searching. See Zegarek's question-thread for details.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS Summarize & quote with credit what is relevant to asking your question & relate it to the rest of your presentation, don't expect readers to read entire other pages or figure out what is relevant ther & how it is relevant. Please act on all the feedback. PS Especially: 1 question. And not a bunch of wonderings, worryings, etc. This post is way too unfocused & unclear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: [Why is a primary-foreign key relation required when we can join without them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5771190/3404097)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To put OP out of their misunderstanding on the main point:

> So how do I link the People and Messages tables together using Primary and Foreign keys?
> ...
>
> I've read that the cross join lets you join tables that do not have a common field ...

To "link tables together" does not need going via keys -- not necessarily any key in any table. The most common linkages in a 1:many join are from Foreign key in the many side to Primary key in the 1 side. That's why those relationships carry those names.

That Primary, Foreign key business is a result of ['normalising'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) the data model, aimed at exactly avoiding 'update anomalies' and making joining straightforward.

Joins going via non-key fields are sometimes call 'cross joins' to distinguish them -- but they're really all just joins, and you can use sql keyword `join ... on ...`.

OP has now revised the q to show `Messages_FNF`. To repeat: no need to go via keys, so you could join `People.email_address` to each/any of the three fields holding email addresses.

Whilst this design is in 1NF (under a very generous interpretation), it is hardly a solution with all that content repeated, including repeating a load of useless `NULL`s. You'll suffer update anomalies (see the wikipage); you'll also indeed get a blowup in numbers of rows.

You need to vertically split off the columns that have repeating (or nullable) fields. Retain `from_addr` in the `Messages` table (because it must have exactly one from address). Create three extra tables each with a compound key of `{message_id, to_addr}` etc, in which `message_id` is a Foreign key to (`REFERENCES`) `Messages`.

Now your sql can't use `join ... on ...` because you're looking for a match in any of the four tables, not all. You'll need a disjunctive `where ... = ... or ... = ... or ...` query. Exercise left for the reader: that's a straightforward piece of sql.

**Addit:** in response to comment

> Each of these three table will have rows upon rows of email addresses that already exist in the People table.

Do they already exist in `People` table? You didn't say that in the original q. I get messages from all sorts of people I've never emailed before; I certainly don't know who else might get bcc'd on messages I receive.

So if you have a business rule that anybody's email address appearing anywhere on any message is to automatically get an entry in the `People` table, yes your auxiliary tables could carry `msg_id, person_id`. You'll still have "rows upon rows" of `person_id`.

You'll still have to query all those `Messages` auxiliary datasets to search for `person_id`; and it still won't be a whole Primary key of any table. (You seem to be worried about efficiency/effort: I'd guess not much saving, on modern DBMSs.)

Comment: Unless i've misunderstood your solution... If I vertically split off the columns that have repeating fields, won't that give me three copies of essentially the same table? 

E.g. the `Message_To`table will contain the fields `msg_id` and `to_addr`. The `Message_Cc` will contain the fields `msg_id` and `cc_addr`,  similarly for the third `Message_Bcc` table. 

Each of these three table will have rows upon rows of email addresses that already exist in the `People` table. Is that not another form of redundancy or is this intentional to avoid looping back to the `People` table?

Answer (score -1):

The Email_Address on People Table is same as From_Address on Messages Table, correct? If it is correct, you can simply join on these two fields. To join the tables, you don't necessarily join on only primary key. You can join on any related fields.

Comment: No, not correct: OP wants to link to _any_ of `from_addr` or `to_addr` (repeating field) or `cc_addr` (repeating field). Because `Messages` has repeating fields, it is not a relation, so incorrect to describe it as a 'table'.

Answer (score -1):

```sql
create table people (person_id text, email_address text);
insert into people values
('001','billy@gmail.com'),('002','bobby@gmail.com'),('003','gregg@gmail.com'),('004','janet@gmail.com'),('005','boss1@gmail.com');

create table messages
( msg_id    text,
  from_addr text,
  to_addr   text[],
  cc_addr   text[],
  bcc_addr  text[] );
insert into messages values
('001','billy@gmail.com','{gregg@gmail.com,dave@gmail.com}','{boss1@gmail.com}',NULL),('002','bobby@gmail.com','{gregg@gmail.com}',NULL,NULL),('003','janet@gmail.com','{boss1@gmail.com}','{bobby@gmail.com}','{gregg@gmail.com}');
```

If like above, you use [`text[]` (array of `text`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) for `to`, `cc` and `bcc` fields (they should allow email to be sent to multiple addresses at once, so it makes sense), you can compare the e-mail from your target `people` row to [`ANY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.30.16) e-mail in an [array that combines](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE) the e-mail addresses in the `messages` table: [online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/1HWHCHca)

```sql
select  m.* 
from    messages as m 
   join people   as p 
   on p.email_address = any(m.from_addr||
                            m.to_addr  ||
                            m.cc_addr  ||
                            m.bcc_addr ) 
where p.person_id='005';
```

The first `||` is `anycompatible||anycompatiblearray` operator that adds an element to array, and the rest of `||` are `anycompatiblearray||anycompatiblearray` that merge arrays. You end up with one array, and `text = any( text[] )` lets you check if your e-mail address is in there.

An intermediate table between `messages` and `people` could hold an attribute saying how they're related (from/to/cc/bcc), plus a single address. This would be easier to work with and index: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/LeaGOuPc)

It might be worth looking into [other ways](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68266/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-an-email-address-in-postgresql) to store an e-mail address instead of a plain `text` type.

Comment: `to_addr`, `cc_addr`, etc have repeating fields, so a bare `=` test won't work.

Comment: Suppose `People.email_address` contains `"bob@gmail.com"` and `Messages.to_addr` includes `"billybob@gmail.com"`. Because you're doing a (sub-)string search, not a proper whole-field comparison, `any` will return a false positive.

Comment: ... Or suppose one field ending `"someone@gmail.com"` concatenated to a field beginning `"abel@gmail.com"`. Now you're going to get a false positive match for `"mabel@gmail.com"`.

Comment: @AntC Here's a demo showing that an array with `billybob@gmail.com` in it is *not* matched with `bob@gmail.com`: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/nwj8FAHS). Again, you seem to be assuming it's text-to-text concatenation, then some sort of text-to-concatenated-text matching. Meanwhile it's text **array** concatenation, merging arrays of text values without affecting the values themselves, then text-to-text one-to-many comparison using the `ANY` operator.

Comment: Then I apologise: I'm trying to guide the OP towards using conventional techniques. I'd call `array`s an advanced feature not supported by all vendors. If arrays are allowed within scope of the question (it doesn't say so), your approach will work. It won't scale to more complex 'repeating groups'. Normalisation is the discipline I'd expect this kind of question to be looking for.