# Implement a "One-to-many" relationship with DataSets

Tags: c#, sql, database, ado.net, dataset

I have two tables, one containing patient information, the other, the notes for each patient.
(One patient, many notes for a patient).

Given this, in the Designer (which you access by right-clicking on the chosen DataSet), how do I create a one-to-many relationship? I have never performed this before.

Secondly, for the patient notes table, how would I add a note to a patient record using SQL syntax? Note, this is *not* updating an existing one, but adding a completely new one to the patientNotes table using the unique patient ID number as the reference (so only that specific patient has that note added to them, not them **and** everyone else).

Answer (score 1):

Very technically speaking, you don't *need* to do anything to create a one-to-many relationship. You just have to have the two tables set up as you have them and use them as you intend on using them. I work in data warehousing and unfortunately a great many of our relationships like this are not formalized with any sort of key or constraint.

The correct way to do it is to implement a foreign key constraint on the patient ID column on the patientNotes table. A FK will only allow you to insert data into patientNotes IF the patient ID exists in the patient table. If you would try to insert a note into your table that has a patient ID that doesn't exist in the patient table, the insert would fail and the SQL engine would give you an error. Note that the column on the patients table that you are creating the FK to must be a primary key.

Inserting data will really go as any other insert would:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.patientNotes (patientId, NoteText)
VALUES(4265, 'During his 8/14/2014 visit, Mr. Cottinsworth complained of chest pains. Evidently he has been wearing a lady''s corset to hide his large gut. Advised the very portly Mr. Cottinsworth to discontinue corset use'
```

You could toss that in a SP, put it in your code and use parameters for the patientId and NoteText, however you wanted to do it.

As far as doing this all in Visual Studio graphically, I can't be of much help there. I typically use the TSQL editor and type out what I want to do to the DB. I'm sure there are tutorials abound on how to set up FKs on Visual Studio.

Further reading:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189049.aspx

http://www.scarydba.com/2010/11/22/do-foreign-key-constraints-help-performance/

[what are the advantages of defining a foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183116/what-are-the-advantages-of-defining-a-foreign-key)

Comment: Hi chipmunk, almost there for the green checkmark. I need you to explain a couple of things to me first, though. What's "4265" mean? Next, how would I implement the FK constraint. Lastly, you're saying a patient ID must already exist in the patientNotes table, right? If so, what would be the SQL syntax I'd use to enter multiple notes under one patient? For example: `"INSERT INTO PatientNotes (consultationNotes) VALUES (@newPatientConsultationNote) WHERE patientID = @patientID";` If this is not correct, what would I do?