# why use foreign key to my tables when i can achieve that with sql joins?

Tags: mysql, sql

my question is what the purpose of using relations between tables , when i can achieve that with joining tables with sql joins ?

Comment: Foreign keys are there to keep data consistent. Nothing to do with joins.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183116/what-are-the-advantages-of-defining-a-foreign-key it shows your answer

Comment: Because you have to. That's why

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's wrong with foreign keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83147/whats-wrong-with-foreign-keys)

Answer (score 0):

Foreign Keys give another layer of safety. They provide data integrity on data level. They prevent you from adding a record which does not fulfill the relation.

For example, if you have a table `users` with three Users (IDs 1, 2 and 3) and another table `entries`, where `entries.uid` has a relation to `users.id`, this means you can't add an entry to `entries` where you would add an `entry.uid` of 4, if you don't have an user with ID 4 defined.