# Laravel MYSQL Foriegn Key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, key

While designing the database for a laravel software using MYSQL, is assigning foreign keys relevant or does Laravel take care of that "Software side".

In the migration we have something like

**Table Example:**

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
```

should i modify the example table in phpmyadmin and make user_id a foreign key? is there a better way or is this not relevant or necessary?

Comment: its not necessary but its nice for data integrity; the database is a good place for enforcing such a constraint

Comment: @lagbox thank you very much, but does it effect the database loading or performance in anyway?

Comment: If you define the name as `user_id`, then Laravel model can detect as  `users` table `id`. But if you define any other name, then you need to tell laravel about the foreign key name, while making relationship on model

Comment: @KhalilGhanem it does affect, because declaring a foreign key in MySQL will create an index that will let the base load more effectively. On a small database, the difference is negligeable, but on bigger you can really see a difference in seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define foreign key constraints in your migration. When using code base you should make all the changes using migrations.

Additionally by defining foreign key you actually build a relation between 2 tables otherwise this relation will be at code level. When relation is built database will restrict to have only values which actually exists in main table. Using foreign key you can also do [cascading (on update and delete)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44956/good-explanation-of-cascade-on-delete-update-behavior) at db level.

Reference [what are the advantages of defining a foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183116/what-are-the-advantages-of-defining-a-foreign-key)

[Why should I use foreign keys in database?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/375704/why-should-i-use-foreign-keys-in-database)

Answer (score -1):

if use Laravel 7 ,you can use this short that is a column name user_id foreign to ID user in the table users :

```
$table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
```